# NgRx With Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, typeerror, ngrx

```
export class Ingredient {
    public name: string;
    public amount: number;

    constructor(name: string, amount: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

**My Array:**

```
export const initialState2: Ingredient[] = [
  new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
  new Ingredient('Lemons', 10),
  new Ingredient('Cherries', 15),
  new Ingredient('Tangerines', 20),
  new Ingredient('Apricots', 25)
];
```

**My NgRx Action:**

```
export const ADD_INGREDIENT2 = createAction(
    'ADD_INGREDIENT2',
    props<{ ingredient: Ingredient }>()
);
```

**and my Reducer:**

```
export const shoppingListReducer = createReducer(
  initialState2,
  on(
    ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT2,
    (state, ingredient) => ({ ...state, ingredients: [...state, ingredient] })
  )
);
```

I'm following a course about Angular. I want to do with the new version, new syntax what was done with the old version using switch/case in that course.

I have an **array** and I want to work **NgRx**.

I want to show the elements inside the array and then add new element to the array.

but I failed. I'm probably making a mistake with some **types**.

And my code at the bottom of the page is **working **but my code in the new version is not working.

**Code in the course:** works perfectly

```
export const initialState = {
  ingredients: [
    new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
    new Ingredient('Lemons', 10),
    new Ingredient('Cherries', 15),
    new Ingredient('Tangerines', 20),
    new Ingredient('Apricots', 25)
  ]
};
________________________________________________________
export const ADD_INGREDIENT = 'ADD_INGREDIENT';

export class AddIngredient implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_INGREDIENT;
    payload: Ingredient;
}
```

```
export function shoppingListReducer(state = initialState, action: ShoppingListActions.AddIngredient) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT:
      return { ...state, ingredients: [...state.ingredients, action.payload] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [NgRx Reducer](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers) you should use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to unpack `ingredient` property and add it to the `ingredients` array with:

```
ingredients: [...state.ingredients, ingredient]
```

Reducer code:

```
export const shoppingListReducer = createReducer(
  initialState2,
  on(ShoppingListActions.ADD_INGREDIENT2,
    (state, { ingredient }) => ({
      ...state,
      ingredients: [...state.ingredients, ingredient],
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Recipes are not loading. I tried this before.

Comment: Please try last answer update

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're using different type of data.

Your state is an array, which denoted by [];
The course's state is an object, denoted by {};

{...} is for object and [...] is for array. That's the root cause of the problem.